# Revert to older version of MoveIt

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I would like to ask whether is it possible to revert MoveIt (on ROS Indigo) to older version (2016)?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255217/revert-to-older-version-of-moveit/) by [Wen Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29388/wen-xin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-02-21**:
May we ask why you want to roll back MoveIt! version? You can open a ticket at https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/ if you want to discuss about it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-22**:
I agree with @130s: it would probably be good if you can tell us why you'd want to do this. A lot of improvements to MoveIt have been added since the last release(s) in 2016, so if you have any problems with those, it'd be good to report them so they can be fixed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-22**:
From your other questions (#q254927 and #q254915), I get the impression that you're mostly struggling with the "robot state validation" feature that was added to the trajectory execution monitor. Is that correct?

**Comment by [Wen Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29388/wen-xin/) on 2017-02-24**:
Yes, im struggling with the "robot state validation" feature, so i thought it will be good if i can use back the previous version of MoveIt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, but you'll have to build it from sources. See [moveit.ros.org/install/source](http://moveit.ros.org/install/source) for details.

---

Edit:

> I'm very new to ROS and MoveIt!.

A bit harsh maybe, but I believe you'd use the same techniques / follow a similar procedure with any open-source software.

> I understand that i have to pull down required repositories and build it within my catkin workspace.

If you follow the steps described on the MoveIt *Install* page that will mostly be done *for* you, but that is the general idea, yes.

> But how do i know which version i will be building?

That is more a general software version control question: typically something like a *tag* (or sometimes a special *branch*) is used to associate a version number with a specific state of the software repository. On GitHub, those tags are then most of the times accompanied by *releases*, that can be found on a special page for a specific repository. For MoveIt, you can find the releases at [ros-planning/moveit/releases](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/releases).

With semantic versioning, releases are always numbered as `major.minor.patch`. MoveIt uses different `minor` numbers for the different ROS distributions that it supports: `9` for Kinetic, `8` for Jade and `7` for Indigo. So you'll want to find a release (tag) that is of the form `0.7.x` if you're targeting Indigo.

Once you've determined the particular release you'd like to build -- and *after* you've completed the `wstool merge ..` and `wstool update` steps from the instructions (but before `rosdep ..`), `cd` into the `moveit`, `moveit_msgs` and `moveit_resources` and do a `git checkout RELEASE_TAG` in each of those directories, where `RELEASE_TAG` is the specific version that you'd like to build. After that you can continue with the rest of the instructions.

Note that not all involved packages have the same versions / tags. You'll have to select a matching set yourself. You could use the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/indigo-devel/moveit/CHANGELOG.rst) or perhaps even the repo sync announcements in the Discourse [release](https://discourse.ros.org/c/release) category.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wen Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29388/wen-xin/) on 2017-02-22**:
Thanks for the reply. I'm very new to ROS and MoveIt!. I understand that i have to pull down required repositories and build it within my catkin workspace. But how do i know which version i will be building?

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2017-02-22**:
Versions are tagged as releases in the MoveIt! github: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/releases

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-22**:
Thanks Dave. Is that not what I wrote in my edit?